# creating task using exact target on salesforce object

Tags: marketing-cloud

How can we create task in salesforce when emails are sent via exacttarget.

.i.e when an email is sent it has create task in salesforce and has to attached to saleforce object

Answer (score 0):

There are a list of AMPscript functions available for ExactTarget emails [here](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_functions_for_use_with_salesforcecom/). This does currently involved some initial steps - outlined [here](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-GB/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_for_appexchange/exacttarget_for_appexchange_configuration_guide_for_salesforce_enterprise_and_unlimited_editions/)